# magento: rewriting templates

Tags: php, xml, layout, magento

I have altered a template file in:

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/tracking.phtml

However i'd like to save this file with these new changes into a new file and leave tracking.phtml in its stock standard form and somehow redirect the block to the location of the new file and use it instead.

Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Shipment_Create_Tracking is the class I think i have to change and i've tried creating a constructor in it and using a few different methods such as Mage::settheme and $this->setTemplate but none of them make a difference.

Any help would be greatly appricated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in the file 'app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml', tracking.phtml is used several times. If this change is for a module then create a layout file '*yourmodule*.xml' and enable it from your config file. Otherwise name it 'local.xml'. It's contents will have to be an update something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>
        <reference name="shipment_tracking">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>your/new/tracking.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>
</layout>
```

Comment: Also if you want to minimize number of copypasted layout statements you can use <update handle="handle_name" /> inside different controller action handles. For example: 
<my_handle_name>
    <reference name="shipment_tracking">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>your/new/tracking.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</my_handle_name>
<adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>
    <update handle="my_handle_name"/>
</adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>

Comment: Works a charm.. thats guys. That is possibly the fastest I have spent on a problem with magento :P.